# Ayuda con busqueda de autoincrementar

Tags: php, mysql, buscador, autoincremento

HOLA amigos una consultita:
tengo una tabla inventario

```
id    codigo   descripcion
01    12345001  envase
02    12346001  caja
03    12345002  envase
04    12346002  caja
```

Yo estoy haciendo un formulario de ingreso de nuevos items al inventario en donde con ayuda de un catalogo busco envase 12345 y luego cuando guarde quiero que se incremente a uno mas osea 12345003, esta probando con esta sentencia pero no me sale:

```
$codigo=$_POST['codigo'];
$e=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT MAX(codigo) FROM detalleinventarioinicial  where substr(codigo,1,5)='$codigo' GROUP by descripcion");
$d=(int) $e;
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO inventario(id,codigo,descripcion) VALUES ('$id','$d','$descripcion')");
```

Comment: Hay algo que no tiendo, cuando dices: "... 12345  y luego cuando guarde que se incremente a uno mas osea 12345003". La diferencia entre 12345 y 12345003 es mas de 1. A que te refieres exactamente con "uno mas"?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: *$id* ¿ya lo tienes previamente inicializado?

Comment: No osea yo busco en un catago de bienes osea  envase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas obtener el resultado del query antes de usarlo y también agregar el +1 para seleccionar el siguiente valor; intenta esto:

```
$codigo = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['codigo']);
$e=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT MAX(codigo) +1 max FROM detalleinventarioinicial  where substr(codigo,1,5)='$codigo' GROUP by descripcion");
$d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($e);
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO inventario(id,codigo,descripcion) VALUES ('$id','$d[max]','$descripcion')");
```

La otra opción es embeber la selección en el insert:

```
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO inventario(id,codigo,descripcion) VALUES ('$id', (SELECT MAX(codigo) + 1 FROM detalleinventarioinicial  where substr(codigo,1,5)='$codigo' GROUP by descripcion") ,'$descripcion')");
```

Comment: gracias voy a probarlo

Comment: hermano gracias en lo que se pideme nomas y te ayudare

Comment: Me da gusto poder ayudar @deivid7777 . Solamente no olvides marcar esta respuesta como correcta si es que resolvió el problema para que se cierre correctamente esta pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: Ah uba consulta amigo Solrac este como cierro una pregunta correctamente.....prinera vez q consulto a este foro

Comment: Está cerrada cuando aceptas la respuesta :)

Saludos.